# java race condition method call with atomic call

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

can the following cause a race condition. The issue i'm looking at, is can there be a context switch between the method call and the atomic call to actionWasCompleted.

```
private final AtomicReference<ActionCompleted> actionWasCompleted;

public void actionWasCompleted(){
    actionWasCompleted.compareAndSet(ActionCompleted.INITIAL, ActionCompleted.COMPLETED);
}
```

If that's true then wouldn't it be the same case with

```
public void actionWasCompleted(){
    synchronized(this){
    ....
    }
}
```

And would that mean there is a difference between the above code and the this

```
public synchronized void actionWasCompleted(){
....
}
```

Comment: Does it matter? A context switch there would be equivalent to a context switch immediately before the call. (Also, context switches aren't an accurate way to think about multithreading.)

Comment: The last two variants of synchronizing are equal. Your method locks when jumping in. The last one always locks when calling the method. In the version with the synchronized block you could do operations before the locked block within the method.

Comment: The question is unclear. What is `....` supposed to mean? In the first code snippet, the only thing we see is a single update of a reference variable. How’s that expected to race? With what?

Comment: Another method  actionWasCompleted.compareAndSet(ActionCompleted.INITIAL, ActionCompleted.INPROGRESS);   Essentially the method is that says it's complete can be called but before this is called actionWasCompleted.compareAndSet(ActionCompleted.INITIAL, ActionCompleted.COMPLETED),  the other method can be call and this can be called actionWasCompleted.compareAndSet(ActionCompleted.INITIAL, ActionCompleted.INPROGRESS);  moving it into an incorrect state.

Answer (score 1):

> is can there be a context switch between the method call and the atomic call to actionWasCompleted.

A context switch can happen at any point.

> And would that mean there is a difference between the above code and the this

The code is equivalent. One is no more or less likely to context switch before the lock is obtained than the other.

An implied question is; "Is there a problem?"

Before the lock is obtained anything can happen, but this is expected behaviour.